# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in Redux Todo application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following code-

Here is the code for visibilityFilter:

```
const visibilityFilter = ( state = "SHOW_All", action ) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
            return action.filter;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Below code is of the getVisibleTodos:

```
const getVisibleTodos= (
    todos = [],
    filter
) => {
    switch(filter){
    case 'SHOW_ALL': 
        return todos;
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
        return todos.filter(
            t => !t.completed
        );
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
            return todos.filter(
                t => t.completed
            );
    }
}

class Todo extends Component {
    render(){
        const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(
            this.props.values,
            this.props.visibilityFilter
        )

    return(

        <div>
            <label>Enter your item</label>
            <br />
            <input 
                type="text" 
                ref = { node => this.input = node }
            />

            <button onClick={() => {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'ADD_TODO',
                    id: nextToDoId++,
                    text: this.input.value
                });
                this.input.value = '';
                }}>
                Submit
            </button>

            <br />

            <ul>
            **{visibleTodos.map(value => <li key={value.id}**
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                    store.dispatch({
                                                        type:     
'TOGGLE_TODO',
                                                        id: value.id
                                                    })
                                                }}
                                                style={{
                                                    textDecoration:
                                                        value.completed 
?
                                                            'line- 
through' :
                                                            'none' 
                                                }}>
                                            {`${value.text} `}
                                        </li>
                                )}
            </ul>

            <p>
                Show: {' '}
                <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
                    All
                </FilterLink>
                {' '}
                <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ACTIVE">
                    Active
                </FilterLink>
                {' '}
                <FilterLink filter="SHOW_COMPLETED">
                    Completed
                </FilterLink>
            </p>

        </div>
        )   
    }
}
```

Specifically I am getting error in the line which contains {visibleTodos.map

I am getting an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I am not able to find a solution to this error. Please help!

I am following the Redux tutorial by Dan Abramov on egghead.io

Comment: Clearly `getVisibleTodos(this.props.values, this.props.visibilityFilter)` is returning `undefined`. Work backwards from there and debug the issue. What is the value of `filter` inside the `getVisibleTodos` function? Why is it that value? You'll never learn how to debug if you ask for the answer.

Comment: did you `mapStateToProps` for your `visibilityFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped the initial state of the visibility filter:

```js
const visibilityFilter = ( state = "SHOW_All", action ) => {
```

You typed `SHOW_All`, while I guess it should be `SHOW_ALL` as in `getVisibleTodos`. This typo causes none of the `switch` cases in `getVisibleTodos` to match. As that `switch` doesn't have a default case, the return value is implicitly `undefined`, leading to the `TypeError` when attempting to call `map()`.